# how to predict an outcome given too many continuous and categorical variables?

Tags: statistics, regression, linear-regression, analytics, logistic-regression

I have a sample dataset wherein I'm trying to figure out if there are strong predictors of student passing an exam (which has the value 0 or 1). However there is a mix of continuous variables and categorical variables (around 100 columns) in the dataset (like mother's profession, city, is_male, is_female etc? Can someone please guide which model and variables should I choose to build a model?

This is what the dataset looks like:
[image: sample image of data set]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove column variables that have 0 observations as they are useless for modeling. Columns that have single values on all rows can also be removed.
They are all referred as zero-variance predictors because there will be no variation by the predictor.

Use `nunique()` function  to summarize number of unique values in each column

```
DataFrame.nunique(axis=0, dropna=True)
```

Use `drop()` to drop useless columns.

```
DataFrame.drop('label', axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Missing values in numeric attributes can be filled with median.
Change the column that has only two kind of values to `boolean` like `null` and  `YD` in "Mentor_Orgs_Column".

Check impact of each `categorical` and `numeric` attribute on target attribute:

For example:

```
print(train[["mothersProfession","Pass"]].groupby(['mothersProfession'],as_idex=False).mean())
#Provides impact of 'mothers profession' on training data.
```

This will help find attributes that will help your prediction.
You can then apply different classifiers on this data using `scikit learn` on a trial and error basis to get different insights.

Comment: thanks Vidya. Your answer was helpful and to the point.